Pyinstaller: Exe throws ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '...'
I'm a new programmer (6 month) and use this forum for the first time. So please allow me missing information and incorrect entries.
I wrote my own logging package, and like to import it into another software from me. In vscode everything working and my package get loaded correctly and can be used. In my venv i can see the files (logging_*.json) under the configs folder, which i missing in the executable.
I like to use my modul without changing something on the pyinstaller with --add-data or adding the generatet spec file. Because i want that someone import my modul and dont need to think about something like that.
I set the repository on github on public:
Logging Repository
This is the folder structure of my logging project:
logging/
├── setup.py
└── bub_logger/
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── bub_logger.py
    ├── configs/
        ├── __init__.py
        ├── logging_console.json
        └── logging_file.json

My Setup.py (dont use wheels at the moment)
from setuptools import find_packages, setup

setup(
    name="bub_logger",
    version="0.0.1",
    packages=find_packages(),
    include_package_data=True,
    long_description=open("README.md").read(),
    long_description_content_type="text/markdown",
    description="A flexible and extendable logging module",
    install_requires=[
        "PyYAML",  # Für YAML-Unterstützung
    ],
    entry_points={
        "console_scripts": [
            "bub_logger=bub_logger:main",
        ],
    },
    package_data={
        "bub_logger": ["configs/*"],
    },
    author="-",
    author_email="-",
    url="-",
    classifiers=[
        "Programming Language :: Python :: 3",
        "License :: OSI Approved :: MIT License",
        "Operating System :: OS Independent",
    ],
    python_requires=">=3.7",
)

how i load the config in bub_logger.py:
import importlib.resources as pkg_resources

load_config(...):
        config_data = None
        for ext in ["json", "yaml", "yml"]:
            try:
                config_file_path = pkg_resources.files("bub_logger.configs").joinpath(
                    f"{config_file}.{ext}"
                )
                with config_file_path.open("r") as file:
                    config_data = file.read()
                    if ext == "json":
                        config = json.loads(config_data)
                    else:
                        config = yaml.safe_load(config_data)
                    break
            except FileNotFoundError:
                continue

        if config_data is None:
            raise FileNotFoundError(f"Configuration file {config_file} not found.")
 ......


How my task in vscode is defined to create the executable with pyinstaller. Its use the .venv interprete so it should load the installed packages -> bub_logger as well.
    {
      "label": "Build",
      "type": "shell",
      "command": "${workspaceFolder}\\.venv\\Scripts\\python",
      "args": [
        "-m",
        "PyInstaller",
        "--noconfirm",
        "--log-level=INFO",
        "--onefile",
        "--windowed",
        "--workpath=.\\BuildTmp",
        "--icon=..\\source\\images\\Prog.ico",
        "..\\openhmi.py"
      ],
      "options": {
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}/build/"
      },
      "dependsOrder": "sequence",
      "dependsOn": ["CompileImages", "mkdirBuild", "Clean"],
      "group": {
        "kind": "build",
        "isDefault": true
      },
      "problemMatcher": []
    },

so if i run the build process and start the executable after this i get the following error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "openhmi.py", line 59, in <module>
  File "bub_logger\bub_logger.py", line 92, in load_config
  File "importlib\resources\_common.py", line 46, in wrapper
  File "importlib\resources\_common.py", line 56, in files
  File "functools.py", line 909, in wrapper
  File "importlib\resources\_common.py", line 82, in _
  File "importlib\__init__.py", line 90, in import_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1387, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1360, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1324, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bub_logger.configs

Here we see the bub_logger is importet and is used from the executable... it just dont find the configs files, which are needed.
what i am doing wrong? I asked chatgpt and other ai but every ai just return me same suggestion, which not working and the ai can't get away from this suggestion anymore.
Thanks in advance.
i have try to get the content of the executable with:
pyi-archive_viewer .\openhmi.exe > test.txt
but it not realy helped me
Contents of 'openhmi.exe' (PKG/CArchive):
 position, length, uncompressed_length, is_compressed, typecode, name
 0, 233, 289, 1, 'm', 'struct'
 233, 3825, 7438, 1, 'm', 'pyimod01_archive'
 4058, 10014, 23131, 1, 'm', 'pyimod02_importers'
 14072, 2731, 6154, 1, 'm', 'pyimod03_ctypes'
 16803, 955, 1684, 1, 'm', 'pyimod04_pywin32'
 17758, 1020, 1835, 1, 's', 'pyiboot01_bootstrap'
 18778, 886, 1530, 1, 's', 'pyi_rth_inspect'
 19664, 677, 1224, 1, 's', 'pyi_rth_pyqt5'
 20341, 1313, 2315, 1, 's', 'pyi_rth_pkgutil'
 21654, 2061, 4058, 1, 's', 'pyi_rth_multiprocessing'
 23715, 1665, 2853, 1, 's', 'openhmi'
 25380, 187392, 590112, 1, 'b', 'PyQt5\\Qt5\\bin\\MSVCP140.dll'
 212772, 14704, 31728, 1, 'b', 'PyQt5\\Qt5\\bin\\MSVCP140_1.dll'
 227476, 2730495, 6023664, 1, 'b', 'PyQt5\\Qt5\\bin\\Qt5Core.dll'
 2957971, 186854, 436720, 1, 'b', 'PyQt5\\Qt5\\bin\\Qt5DBus.dll'
 3144825, 2617501, 7008240, 1, 'b', 'PyQt5\\Qt5\\bin\\Qt5Gui.dll'
 5762326, 568060, 1340400, 1, 'b', 'PyQt5\\Qt5\\bin\\Qt5Network.dll'
 6330386, 1384258, 3591664, 1, 'b', 'PyQt5\\Qt5\\bin\\Qt5Qml.dll'
 7714644, 188610, 438768, 1, 'b', 'PyQt5\\Qt5\\bin\\Qt5QmlModels.dll'
 7903254, 1620975, 4148720, 1, 'b', 'PyQt5\\Qt5\\bin\\Qt5Quick.dll'
 9524229, 134827, 330736, 1, 'b', 'PyQt5\\Qt5\\bin\\Qt5Svg.dll'
 9659056, 60405, 149488, 1, 'b', 'PyQt5\\Qt5\\bin\\Qt5WebSockets.dll'
 9719461, 2486436, 5498352, 1, 'b', 'PyQt5\\Qt5\\bin\\Qt5Widgets.dll'
 12205897, 22414, 44528, 1, 'b', 'PyQt5\\Qt5\\bin\\VCRUNTIME140_1.dll'
 12228311, 1750408, 4173928, 1, 'b', 'PyQt5\\Qt5\\bin\\d3dcompiler_47.dll'
 13978719, 11075, 25072, 1, 'b', 'PyQt5\\Qt5\\bin\\libEGL.dll'
 13989794, 1279082, 3385328, 1, 'b', 'PyQt5\\Qt5\\bin\\libGLESv2.dll'
 15268876, 7763398, 20923392, 1, 'b', 'PyQt5\\Qt5\\bin\\opengl32sw.dll'
 23032274, 30839, 68080, 1, 'b', 'PyQt5\\Qt5\\plugins\\generic\\qtuiotouchplugin.dll'
 23063113, 19828, 41968, 1, 'b', 'PyQt5\\Qt5\\plugins\\iconengines\\qsvgicon.dll'
 23082941, 19831, 39408, 1, 'b', 'PyQt5\\Qt5\\plugins\\imageformats\\qgif.dll'
 23102772, 21660, 45040, 1, 'b', 'PyQt5\\Qt5\\plugins\\imageformats\\qicns.dll'
 23124432, 18524, 38384, 1, 'b', 'PyQt5\\Qt5\\plugins\\imageformats\\qico.dll'
 23142956, 121065, 421360, 1, 'b', 'PyQt5\\Qt5\\plugins\\imageformats\\qjpeg.dll'
 23264021, 15397, 32240, 1, 'b', 'PyQt5\\Qt5\\plugins\\imageformats\\qsvg.dll'
 23279418, 15033, 31728, 1, 'b', 'PyQt5\\Qt5\\plugins\\imageformats\\qtga.dll'
 23294451, 136072, 390128, 1, 'b', 'PyQt5\\Qt5\\plugins\\imageformats\\qtiff.dll'
 23430523, 14444, 30192, 1, 'b', 'PyQt5\\Qt5\\plugins\\imageformats\\qwbmp.dll'
 23444967, 243280, 510448, 1, 'b', 'PyQt5\\Qt5\\plugins\\imageformats\\qwebp.dll'
 23688247, 447370, 844784, 1, 'b', 'PyQt5\\Qt5\\plugins\\platforms\\qminimal.dll'
 24135617, 402492, 754672, 1, 'b', 'PyQt5\\Qt5\\plugins\\platforms\\qoffscreen.dll'
 24538109, 188469, 482288, 1, 'b', 'PyQt5\\Qt5\\plugins\\platforms\\qwebgl.dll'
 24726578, 726834, 1477104, 1, 'b', 'PyQt5\\Qt5\\plugins\\platforms\\qwindows.dll'
 25453412, 29636, 68592, 1, 'b', 'PyQt5\\Qt5\\plugins\\platformthemes\\qxdgdesktopportal.dll'
 25483048, 68007, 144368, 1, 'b', 'PyQt5\\Qt5\\plugins\\styles\\qwindowsvistastyle.dll'
 25551055, 738447, 2482176, 1, 'b', 'PyQt5\\QtCore.pyd'
 26289502, 719707, 2490880, 1, 'b', 'PyQt5\\QtGui.pyd'
 27009209, 1313056, 5160960, 1, 'b', 'PyQt5\\QtWidgets.pyd'
 28322265, 55154, 120320, 1, 'b', 'PyQt5\\sip.cp312-win_amd64.pyd'
 28377419, 58206, 119192, 1, 'b', 'VCRUNTIME140.dll'
 28435625, 25850, 49528, 1, 'b', 'VCRUNTIME140_1.dll'
 28461475, 45480, 84760, 1, 'b', '_bz2.pyd'
 28506955, 58434, 125208, 1, 'b', '_ctypes.pyd'
 28565389, 120859, 252696, 1, 'b', '_decimal.pyd'
 28686248, 29946, 65816, 1, 'b', '_hashlib.pyd'
 28716194, 88542, 159512, 1, 'b', '_lzma.pyd'
 28804736, 19483, 35096, 1, 'b', '_multiprocessing.pyd'
 28824219, 17975, 32536, 1, 'b', '_queue.pyd'
 28842194, 39925, 83224, 1, 'b', '_socket.pyd'
 28882119, 70879, 177432, 1, 'b', '_ssl.pyd'
 28952998, 20138, 36632, 1, 'b', '_wmi.pyd'
 28973136, 1859475, 5191960, 1, 'b', 'libcrypto-3.dll'
 30832611, 23195, 39696, 1, 'b', 'libffi-8.dll'
 30855806, 282334, 787224, 1, 'b', 'libssl-3.dll'
 31138140, 96982, 199448, 1, 'b', 'pyexpat.pyd'
 31235122, 23160, 68376, 1, 'b', 'python3.dll'
 31258282, 2580097, 7009048, 1, 'b', 'python312.dll'
 33838379, 17476, 30488, 1, 'b', 'select.pyd'
 33855855, 417900, 1137944, 1, 'b', 'unicodedata.pyd'
 34273755, 92814, 222720, 1, 'b', 'yaml\\_yaml.cp312-win_amd64.pyd'
 34366569, 110, 130, 1, 'x', 'PyQt5\\Qt5\\translations\\qt_ar.qm'
 34366679, 119, 153, 1, 'x', 'PyQt5\\Qt5\\translations\\qt_bg.qm'
 34366798, 119, 153, 1, 'x', 'PyQt5\\Qt5\\translations\\qt_ca.qm'
 34366917, 124, 157, 1, 'x', 'PyQt5\\Qt5\\translations\\qt_cs.qm'
 34367041, 121, 153, 1, 'x', 'PyQt5\\Qt5\\translations\\qt_da.qm'
 34367162, 120, 153, 1, 'x', 'PyQt5\\Qt5\\translations\\qt_de.qm'
 34367282, 25, 16, 1, 'x', 'PyQt5\\Qt5\\translations\\qt_en.qm'
 34367307, 118, 153, 1, 'x', 'PyQt5\\Qt5\\translations\\qt_es.qm'
 34367425, 77186, 293121, 1, 'x', 'PyQt5\\Qt5\\translations\\qt_fa.qm'
 34444611, 97, 117, 1, 'x', 'PyQt5\\Qt5\\translations\\qt_fi.qm'
 34444708, 119, 153, 1, 'x', 'PyQt5\\Qt5\\translations\\qt_fr.qm'
 34444827, 76, 70, 1, 'x', 'PyQt5\\Qt5\\translations\\qt_gd.qm'
 34444903, 78978, 323590, 1, 'x', 'PyQt5\\Qt5\\translations\\qt_gl.qm'
 34523881, 78, 83, 1, 'x', 'PyQt5\\Qt5\\translations\\qt_he.qm'
 34523959, 2804, 8743, 1, 'x', 'PyQt5\\Qt5\\translations\\qt_help_ar.qm'
 34526763, 3125, 10599, 1, 'x', 'PyQt5\\Qt5\\translations\\qt_help_bg.qm'
 34529888, 2224, 7444, 1, 'x', 'PyQt5\\Qt5\\translations\\qt_help_ca.qm'
 34532112, 3810, 15297, 1, 'x', 'PyQt5\\Qt5\\translations\\qt_help_cs.qm'
 34535922, 1524, 4795, 1, 'x', 'PyQt5\\Qt5\\translations\\qt_help_da.qm'
 34537446, 2311, 7570, 1, 'x', 'PyQt5\\Qt5\\translations\\qt_help_de.qm'
 34539757, 25, 16, 1, 'x', 'PyQt5\\Qt5\\translations\\qt_help_en.qm'
 34539782, 3103, 10704, 1, 'x', 'PyQt5\\Qt5\\translations\\qt_help_es.qm'
 34542885, 3090, 10922, 1, 'x', 'PyQt5\\Qt5\\translations\\qt_help_fr.qm'
 34545975, 3187, 10891, 1, 'x', 'PyQt5\\Qt5\\translations\\qt_help_gl.qm'
 34549162, 3114, 10284, 1, 'x', 'PyQt5\\Qt5\\translations\\qt_help_hu.qm'
 34552276, 3050, 10612, 1, 'x', 'PyQt5\\Qt5\\translations\\qt_help_it.qm'
 34555326, 2760, 7917, 1, 'x', 'PyQt5\\Qt5\\translations\\qt_help_ja.qm'
 34558086, 2034, 5708, 1, 'x', 'PyQt5\\Qt5\\translations\\qt_help_ko.qm'
 34560120, 2882, 9673, 1, 'x', 'PyQt5\\Qt5\\translations\\qt_help_pl.qm'
 34563002, 2282, 7288, 1, 'x', 'PyQt5\\Qt5\\translations\\qt_help_ru.qm'
 34565284, 3260, 10388, 1, 'x', 'PyQt5\\Qt5\\translations\\qt_help_sk.qm'
 34568544, 3181, 10363, 1, 'x', 'PyQt5\\Qt5\\translations\\qt_help_sl.qm'
 34571725, 1564, 4629, 1, 'x', 'PyQt5\\Qt5\\translations\\qt_help_tr.qm'
 34573289, 3108, 9750, 1, 'x', 'PyQt5\\Qt5\\translations\\qt_help_uk.qm'
 34576397, 2531, 6441, 1, 'x', 'PyQt5\\Qt5\\translations\\qt_help_zh_CN.qm'
 34578928, 3150, 9301, 1, 'x', 'PyQt5\\Qt5\\translations\\qt_help_zh_TW.qm'
 34582078, 114, 146, 1, 'x', 'PyQt5\\Qt5\\translations\\qt_hu.qm'
 34582192, 119, 153, 1, 'x', 'PyQt5\\Qt5\\translations\\qt_it.qm'
 34582311, 115, 146, 1, 'x', 'PyQt5\\Qt5\\translations\\qt_ja.qm'
 34582426, 115, 146, 1, 'x', 'PyQt5\\Qt5\\translations\\qt_ko.qm'
 34582541, 46643, 165383, 1, 'x', 'PyQt5\\Qt5\\translations\\qt_lt.qm'
 34629184, 86, 89, 1, 'x', 'PyQt5\\Qt5\\translations\\qt_lv.qm'
 34629270, 128, 161, 1, 'x', 'PyQt5\\Qt5\\translations\\qt_pl.qm'
 34629398, 18980, 70334, 1, 'x', 'PyQt5\\Qt5\\translations\\qt_pt.qm'
 34648378, 130, 164, 1, 'x', 'PyQt5\\Qt5\\translations\\qt_ru.qm'
 34648508, 124, 157, 1, 'x', 'PyQt5\\Qt5\\translations\\qt_sk.qm'
 34648632, 61702, 228428, 1, 'x', 'PyQt5\\Qt5\\translations\\qt_sl.qm'
 34710334, 18206, 65851, 1, 'x', 'PyQt5\\Qt5\\translations\\qt_sv.qm'
 34728540, 91, 110, 1, 'x', 'PyQt5\\Qt5\\translations\\qt_tr.qm'
 34728631, 131, 164, 1, 'x', 'PyQt5\\Qt5\\translations\\qt_uk.qm'
 34728762, 40216, 117347, 1, 'x', 'PyQt5\\Qt5\\translations\\qt_zh_CN.qm'
 34768978, 107, 141, 1, 'x', 'PyQt5\\Qt5\\translations\\qt_zh_TW.qm'
 34769085, 48163, 160017, 1, 'x', 'PyQt5\\Qt5\\translations\\qtbase_ar.qm'
 34817248, 47497, 165337, 1, 'x', 'PyQt5\\Qt5\\translations\\qtbase_bg.qm'
 34864745, 57942, 210159, 1, 'x', 'PyQt5\\Qt5\\translations\\qtbase_ca.qm'
 34922687, 50353, 174701, 1, 'x', 'PyQt5\\Qt5\\translations\\qtbase_cs.qm'
 34973040, 51815, 181387, 1, 'x', 'PyQt5\\Qt5\\translations\\qtbase_da.qm'
 35024855, 59624, 220467, 1, 'x', 'PyQt5\\Qt5\\translations\\qtbase_de.qm'
 35084479, 25, 16, 1, 'x', 'PyQt5\\Qt5\\translations\\qtbase_en.qm'
 35084504, 46937, 165170, 1, 'x', 'PyQt5\\Qt5\\translations\\qtbase_es.qm'
 35131441, 50753, 179941, 1, 'x', 'PyQt5\\Qt5\\translations\\qtbase_fi.qm'
 35182194, 46368, 166167, 1, 'x', 'PyQt5\\Qt5\\translations\\qtbase_fr.qm'
 35228562, 50693, 189580, 1, 'x', 'PyQt5\\Qt5\\translations\\qtbase_gd.qm'
 35279255, 42852, 138690, 1, 'x', 'PyQt5\\Qt5\\translations\\qtbase_he.qm'
 35322107, 46650, 160494, 1, 'x', 'PyQt5\\Qt5\\translations\\qtbase_hu.qm'
 35368757, 45046, 161172, 1, 'x', 'PyQt5\\Qt5\\translations\\qtbase_it.qm'
 35413803, 43169, 129911, 1, 'x', 'PyQt5\\Qt5\\translations\\qtbase_ja.qm'
 35456972, 52269, 156799, 1, 'x', 'PyQt5\\Qt5\\translations\\qtbase_ko.qm'
 35509241, 44974, 153608, 1, 'x', 'PyQt5\\Qt5\\translations\\qtbase_lv.qm'
 35554215, 46899, 162982, 1, 'x', 'PyQt5\\Qt5\\translations\\qtbase_pl.qm'
 35601114, 58556, 203767, 1, 'x', 'PyQt5\\Qt5\\translations\\qtbase_ru.qm'
 35659670, 37339, 125763, 1, 'x', 'PyQt5\\Qt5\\translations\\qtbase_sk.qm'
 35697009, 56449, 194487, 1, 'x', 'PyQt5\\Qt5\\translations\\qtbase_tr.qm'
 35753458, 46633, 158274, 1, 'x', 'PyQt5\\Qt5\\translations\\qtbase_uk.qm'
 35800091, 45464, 127849, 1, 'x', 'PyQt5\\Qt5\\translations\\qtbase_zh_TW.qm'
 35845555, 544159, 1703997, 1, 'x', 'base_library.zip'
 36389714, 157527, 290282, 1, 'x', 'certifi\\cacert.pem'
 36547241, 8, 0, 1, 'x', 'certifi\\py.typed'
 36547249, 2317932, 2317932, 0, 'z', 'PYZ-00.pyz'
? ? 



I too am new but I did run into a similar issue with a python package (pyodbc) and found that I had to manually add it by using '--hidden-import "pyodbc"'. For some reason it is only that package pyinstaller was not able to pick up.

Many thanks for your response. I've been waiting for answers all along :). But as I already wrote, the import of the application looks good. Because the traceback shows the error when loading the bub_logger.configs module and not when loading the bub_logger. The error occurs with load_config() as described above. Nevertheless many thanks. The --hiden-import is required if you load a package during runtime. In other words, in an if condition etc. or if the packet is not recognized in the static analysis. So that's how I understood it :P

i tried a lot and the only solution that i found, was to add the file with

--add-data

after adding the configs with pyinstaller --add-data everything is working.
I've tried to avoid this, but can't find any other solution.
